# Ajax authentication to Spring Security from external application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, spring-security

**Hello all**,

Could you please help me to solve some problem ? I need use some API for my application . At first, I need login to server.

I try to do it, using ajax post request [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RvWb4/34/) :

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://apps.dhis2.org/demo/dhis-web-commons-security/login.action',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                j_username: 'admin',
                j_password: 'district'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Success!!!');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Fail!');
            }
   });
```

But this example only work, when I call this post from app which has the **same domain as server**. So how I can run it from **external app** ?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that your back-end is able to handle CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) or cross-domain requests. 
On your ajax code add this attribute "crossDomain : true".